# Auth not working after successful login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

The user logs out after redirecting to the homepage after successful login. Even a before filter for auth fails on the route. I am using ollieread/multi-auth plugin.

### Auth Controller

```
public function postLogin()
{
    if (\Auth::biz()->attempt(\Input::only(array('email', 'password')), \Input::get('persist', 'no') == 'yes')) {
        // dd(Auth::biz()->check()); returns true
        return \Redirect::route('main.home');
    } else {
        return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('loginFail', true);
    }
}
```

### Route

```
Route::get('/{verify_token?}', array('as' => 'main.home', 'uses' => 'MainController@getIndex'));
```

### Main Controller

```
public function getIndex($verify_token = '')
{
    dd(\Auth::biz()->check()); // returns bool(false)
    return \View::make('main.pages.home', array($emailVerified));
}
```

Comment: have you managed to fix it? im having the same proble whit laravel 5, on the login controller the user is authenticated, but after (or during) redirection it get deauth'd

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco I made a workaround. I login it the usual way but also make a variable storing the email in the session to serve as indicator for successful login. I have HTTPS so its fine. It defeats much of its purpose but still better than nothing.